# Next 13 - client side data fetch

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js v13.3.1 and i try to do API call in client component.
Here is my code:

```
  const [people, setPeople] = useState<null | Person[]>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("people_api", {
          method: "GET",
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setPeople(data as Person[]);
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Everything working fine untill i want to make build. After npm run build I recived error message:

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
> /people/page: /people

When i remove API call problem disappear and build it's ok.

Comment: are you using "use client" on top of the component?

Comment: @KannuMandora jest, I'm using "use client"

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `API` in a wrong manner. Try this...

```
        const response = await fetch("/api/people_api", {
          method: "GET",
          });
```

create a folder in `people_api` in your `api` folder which is located in if you're using `app directory` then the path is

`app/api/people_api/route.ts`